# find if element appears n times in a row in python list

Tags: python, list

```
myList = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

I want to find if True appears 3 times in a row.

I can find it by doing:

```
for x0, x1, x2 in zip(myList, myList[1:], myList[2:]):
    if x0 == True and x1 == True and x2 == True:
        print True
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: As a general note, python treats ```if bool == True``` and ```if bool``` as the same

Comment: Honestly, what you have isn't bad . . . you could shortcut it a little for your case:  `for elems in zip(...):  if all(elems): print True`...  `itertools.islicing` the may not be a horrible idea either if you want to be able to short-circuit efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group elements, then count each group. Using the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) lets you exit the loop early if a match was found:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

print any(sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) == 3 for k, g in groupby(myList) if k)
```

The `if k` filters the groups to only count the groups of `True` values.

The [`itertools.islice()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) ensures we only look at the first 3 elements of a group, and ignore the rest of that group. This way you avoid having to count the next however many `True` values just to determine that you found at least 3.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, islice
>>> myList = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
>>> [sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) for k, g in groupby(myList) if k]
[2, 1, 1]
>>> any(sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) == 3 for k, g in groupby(myList) if k)
False
>>> myList = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]
>>> [sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) for k, g in groupby(myList) if k]
[2, 3, 1]
>>> any(sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) == 3 for k, g in groupby(myList) if k)
True
```

I used a list comprehension to show the group sizes (counting only `True` groups) to show why the `any()` call returns `False` first, then `True`; the second example has a group of 4 consecutive `True` values.

Comment: Is `itertools` built in? Also, is the `print any(sum(1 for _ in islice(g, 3)) == 3 for k, g in groupby(myList) if k)` a boolean?

Answer (score 3):

I like the brevity of the `groupby`, but I find the following slightly more readable so I thought I'd add an alternative;

```
needle = 3 * [True]
any(1 for i in range(len(myList)) if myList[i:i+len(needle)] == needle)
```

Comment: Nice. You can also easily switch `any` to `sum` if you want to count the (possibly overlapping) matches.  (It looks like you have a typo, though, with the `++`.)

Comment: Python is quite savy when dealing with out-of-bond indices in slices, but my FORTRANesque nature would have bent me to write `any(1 for i in range(len(myList)-len(needle)+1) ... ` ;-) +1 for brevity .AND. readability

Comment: This gets slower when looking for long runs of the same element, because it looks at each element _k_ times.  That said, a variation of the same approach would be `needle in (myList[i:i+len(needle)] for i in range(len(myList)))`, eliminating the use of `any()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is my solution

```
% cat hsol.py
import itertools

myList = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]

def test_sequentiality(l, item, n):

    if n>len(l): return False
    s = 0
    for i in l:
        if i != item:
            s = 0
        else:
            s = s+1
            if s == n: return True

    return False

print test_sequentiality(myList, True, 3)
print test_sequentiality(myList, True, 2)
% python2 hsol.py
False
True
%
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to reduce the if statements etc in your question, and directly print the boolean value.

```
for x0, x1, x2 in zip(myList, myList[1:], myList[2:]):
    print x0 == x1 == x2 == True
```

Using `any` statement, we can short circuit the same

```
any(x0 == x1 == x2 == True for (x0, x1, x2) in zip(myList, myList[1:], myList[2:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print reduce(
             lambda acc, x: (acc[0]+1 if x else 0, max(acc[0], acc[1])),
             myList+[None],
             (0, 0)
             )[1]
```

It will accumulate the sequential counts of `True` with maximal count of sequential `True`s `+[None]` is needed in case the longest sequence ends with last element.

Comment: This is just an obfuscated version of the for loop in gboffi's answer.

Comment: Why the `+[None]`, by the way?

Comment: @SvenMarnach it is functional approach to the problem. Honestly I would write loop in my code, it is much more sane. +[None] the maximal sequential count is increased on next element, so it last element is True then last max will yield previous count and not really maximal.

Comment: @SvenMarnach if you have TTFTTT the reduce will yield internally (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2) and the result will be (3, 2). So you need to flush it to become (0, 3).

Comment: Ah, I see.  You could also use `max(reduce(...))` to take the bigger of the two values after the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and (in my opinion) very easy-to-understand way:

```
myList = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
v = True  # search for this value
n = 3  # number of consecutive appearances of v
vList = [v] * n

for i in range(len(myList) - n):
    if myList[i:i + n] == vList:
        print True
        break
else:
    print False
```

It's kind of C-style (or Pascal or Fortran, etc.), but simple.  The above code assumes you just want a single `True` or `False` at the end.  You can easily adapt it if you want to print the index of each found occurrence.